# pandas set cell length

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I sometime want to read the output dataframe and want it to be indented.
For example, if I have dataframe

```
A     |B     |C     |D     |     E
abc|def|ghij|k|ooo
lorem|ipsumjkl|d|amet|hel
```

And I have a list of length I want to apply `alist = [5,8,4,1,3]`

```
A    |B       |C   |D|E
abc  |def     |ghij|k|ooo
lorem|ipsumjkl|dol |a|hel
```

I come up with this,

```py
df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).ljust(elem) for elem in alist).to_csv("report.csv", sep="|", index=False)
```

But I get this error,

```
TypeError: ("'generator' object is not callable", 'occured at index xxxx')
```

How can I have output csv file with the given length list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for i,colum in enumerate(list(df.columns)):

    df[colum]=df[colum].apply(lambda x: str(x).ljust(alist[i]))

df.to_csv("report.csv", sep="|", index=False)
```

Or, you can try this:

```
def returncolumindex(val):
    i, j = np.where(df.values == val)
    return j[0]

df=df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).ljust(alist[returncolumindex(x)]))
```

Comment: I tried this one, but am feeling like it is slow?? I may be wrong, but when I executed, it was slow.It works though!

Comment: Idk,  when I executed, it wasn't slow. But I found another way, check my answer. Although for me, the second option was slower.